# Should I avoid using interactive mode?

Tags: haskell, interactive

Haskell newbie here. I use `ghci` to implement a baby `quicksort` algorithm [1] as follows:

```
Prelude> quicksort (firstx:xs) = quicksort[x|x<-xs, x<firstx] ++ [firstx] ++ quicksort[x|x<-xs, not(x<firstx)]
Prelude> quicksort [] = []
```

The command `quicksort [1,2,3]` then gives an error:

> *** Exception: :8:1-17: Non-exhaustive patterns in function quicksort

However, typing the exact same thing in an `quicksort.hs` file and running `$ ghci quicksort.hs` do not yield such an error.

#### Question

What makes the difference? Is it a rule of thumb that one should avoid using interactive mode?

Reference

[1] Rex Page. Two Dozen Short Lessons in Haskell

Comment: Use `:{` and `:}` around a multi-line statement. Right now the interpreter things you *defined* a new function that happens to have the same name as the one in the previous line.

Comment: It's simpler if you write your code in a file and load it in GHCi. GHCi is not very convenient to use for multi-line definitions like the one above, requiring one to enter multi-line mode with `:{` or to write everything in one line e.g. `qsort [] = [] ; qsort (x:xs) = ...`. Using a file also makes it much easier to tinker around: we can experiment, make a small change, experiment again, make another change, and so on. Reloading is only a "save" & `:r` away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally easier to define a multi-line function in a file and then load `:l <module>` or reload `:r`, but I do sometimes declare a multi-line function directly in GHCi starting with `:{` and `:}`:

```hs
:{
quicksort (firstx:xs) = quicksort[x|x<-xs, x<firstx] ++ [firstx] ++ quicksort[x|x<-xs, not(x<firstx)]
quicksort [] = []
:}
```

`:h` is useful if you forget any commands while in GHCi.

Edit: forget to address the second part of your question.

> Is it a rule of thumb that one should avoid using interactive mode?

Interactive mode is a great tool and I miss it in other ecosystems like ReasonML that do not have one. There is no reason to avoid it. Just remember to copy your code over if you come up with some that you want to keep.

Comment: Bummer.. that means I have to either open two windows, or jump back and forth from ghci to vim.. :(

Comment: @Student if you are using mac or linux there is a great tool called tmux. Install it then open a terminal, type `tmux`, then split it into two windows. You can have ghci and vim in each window and see both at the same time. https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~ckuehl/tmux/